# How can I add pagination to the comments of advanced forum in drupal 7?

Tags: nodes

I use Drupal 7 but don't see any pagination on the comment pages, how can I add a pager there please?

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/141381) can help you.

Let me know if this is working.

Comment: hi mixerowsky, thanks a lot for your quick answer. unfortenutaly this did not worked on my side. i can see a page ron the topic list but found no solution even the link you have sent me to get the pagination on the comments working. may i missing to put a special render code to display the pager? thanks!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.